# string or binary data would be truncated when using batched inserts

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, records

I'm using **SQL Server 2008 R2** and am trying to insert some records from one table to another using the form:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT ... From table1
```

And am receiving the dreaded error.

> "string or binary data would be truncated"

`table1` is a view to another database from which we are taking records and doing some processing of the data before inserting them into `table2` which is a table in the database.

I assumed that this message meant that one of the fields I'm populating is too small to hold the data I'm inserting, but it doesn't appear to be the case.

The select does some parsing of the fields from `table 1` and inserts those values into `table2`. However the inserted data is smaller than the original fields (being only part of the original field) and I have checked to confirm that they all fit into the fields they are being inserted into.

I'm struggling to find the real cause of this problem as the fields in `table2` are all of sufficient size and type to hold the data that will be added to them.

Additionally, when I limited the number of records to be added (doing it in batches to try and find the offending record) it would run without error for 2-3 batches of **10k records** before getting this error. So i thought it was in the next 10k records where there was some anomalous data.

However, when I reduced the batch size to **6k records**, instead of getting the error at the second batch (records **6k-12k**) which is where the problem data should have been, I was able to run the insert without error another 10 times (60k records in total) before the error happened again.

Then I reduced the batch size to **3k** records and was able to run it another 4 times (**12k** records) before seeing the error.

I kept reducing the size of the batch and each time I could insert more records using multiple smaller batches than I could with a single bigger batch.

This would suggest that it's not actually the size of the data being inserted that is causing the problem, but some other aspect.

It has now got to the point where I can no longer insert a single record. Inspecting the record to be inserted confirms that it complies with the sizes of all the fields and should not be causing this error.

Given that initially I couldn't insert the next **10k** records because of this error, but have managed to insert over 100k records (in ever decreasing batch sizes) I was wondering if anyone could suggest where the real problem lies?

**The question is:**
Is there some system table, log or some other limit that may be blocking these inserts?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that your parsing code doesn't try to create a loss of data. Maybe a cast of a VARCHAR field down to a smaller VARCHAR field?

Comment: Error you mentioned is always because of mismatching column length. Since you are doing some manipulation before insert into table2 do check your column lengths using the below link 
http://raresql.com/2014/01/03/sql-server-a-quick-solution-to-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-using-stored-procedure/
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
add the above line top of the code. Also please mention the complete column list instead of using insert into table2 select * from tablename

Comment: For sure your view have one column with the length bigger than the table you want to insert. Try to check that before doing the insert. Try to select the view and analise the data. Maybe, the data you'll lose is important to you...